# Postgres: Strategies for optimizing access to recent data

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

If we have the following requirements:

- Data is frequently inserted into the database
- We want to have fast access to the latest rows
- We can tolerate slower access to older rows

What are the best strategies that we can use in Postgres?

---

To give a concrete toy example:

We have a Slack-like chat application, and we are storing chat messages into the database. Access to the latest messages in any channel needs to be fast, but fast access to messages from a month is not necessary.

Comment: Partitioning on a timestamp and moving old partitions to slower disks comes to mind

Comment: Also, you could have indexes on the recent data, which you drop for older data. All this only works if the time is always in the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Recently used data will naturally be cached.  Is that not enough?

Comment: How do you implement the queries for "recent" data?  `WHERE timestamp_col > :val`?  `ORDER BY timestamp_col LIMIT 5`?

Comment: @jjanes Yes, timestamp-based.